# Replace if a File name exists in a directory

Tags: java, file

This is the code I tried. But this returns false even if the file exists. The variables FilePath and FileName is obtained from the UI.

```
File exportFile = new File("\""+FilePath + "\\"+ FileName+"\"");  
boolean exists = exportFile.exists();  

if (!exists) {  

    System.out.println("File does not exists");               
}
else{  

    System.out.println( "File exists.");                                      
}
```

What is the proper way to do this? And BTW, How can I prompt the user to replace or rename the FileName?

Comment: Is this the full path to the file?

Comment: Yes. If I choose the desktop, it returns C:\Users\Gapchoos\Desktop

Comment: Remove that extra double quotes from the beginning and end of your path.. in the first line.. Your path is already a string, no need to enclose it within extra quotes..

Comment: And remove the extra quotes at the beginning

Comment: @RohitJain thanks this solves the 1st issue. How can I prompt the user to replace or rename the file?

Comment: @Gapchoos.. You can send a message on UI side if the file already exists.. User can then select whether he wants to replace or rename..

Comment: What are you using for UI?? JSP??

Comment: No Java. Am currently working in eclipse.

Comment: But for UI you must be using something right?? Swing, AWT, or anything else??

Comment: Please ask about the renaming in a different question.

Comment: @RohitJain No I use core Java for creating UI also

Comment: Use the advice of @Adam. Post a different question for this..

Comment: ok Thanks @RohitJain and all others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
File exportFile = new File("\""+FilePath + "\\"+ FileName+"\"");
```

with

```
File exportFile = new File(FilePath + "\\" + FileName);
```

There is no need for quoting the file name. Even if it contains spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be caused by the way you get the file path, since you are getting it from UI, i should point out that you don't have to construct the path, you can either use `getAbsolutePath()` or `getPath()` methods provided in the `java.io.File` class.